How to request Youtube Members API access?
I would like to know how to request access permission for membership API.
I am wondering where I should inquire to gain access permission.
Tried to make this request on OAuth 2.0 Playground and always got the same response.
Doc says that I must contact my youtube representative but I don't know where.
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.", 
    "code": 403, 
    "errors": [
      {
        "reason": "forbidden", 
        "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.", 
        "domain": "youtube.common"
      }
    ]
  }
}

